# Stripe: Do you have to use Stripe Elements if you use Connect with Custom Accounts and hosted verifications?

Tags: stripe-payments

I built out my checkout form with Stripe Elements for my checkout form and also use Stripe's Custom account and hosted verifications ( https://stripe.com/docs/connect/custom-accounts ).  Can I switch to Stripe's new checkout ( https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout ) instead of Stripe Elements while maintaining the Custom account and hosted verifications??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you'd just create the Checkout Session on behalf of your connected account by using the Stripe-Account header: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/connect